Why cant I run successfully two test files appium and webdriverio?
When running android mobile tests using appium 2.5.4, uiAutomator2-server: 3.5.0, I encountered some issues. Sometimes 1 of the tests would pass but most of the time the tests would fail with the error below
```An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command. Original error: POST /element cannot be proxied to UiAutomator2 server because the instrumentation process is not running (probably crashed). Check the server log and/or the logcat output for more details.```

I have uninstalled the app and tried to run test again but it keeps failing. Also , how can close the app after running each test? I have tried driver.closeApp but none seem to be working
